# tidy way to perform joins iteratively with map / apply functions

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, purrr, tibble

I would like to join/merge multiple tibbles/data frames with the use of `map`/`lapply`. How would it be possible to perform that?

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble::tibble(rank = rep(stringr::str_c("rank",1:10),10),
                      char_1 = sample(c("a","b","c"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                      points = sample(1:10000, size = 100)
                      )
my_top <- seq(10,90, by= 10) %>% 
  as.list() %>% 
  set_names(c(stringr::str_c("sample_",1:9)))

my_list_1 <- map(my_top , ~ df %>% 
sample_n(.x) %>% 
mutate(!!str_c(.x, "_score") := sample(1:10000, size = .x)))
```

I would like to perform this:

```
df  %>% group_by(rank, char_1, points) %>% 
left_join(my_list_1[[1]] ) %>% 
left_join(my_list_1[[2]] ) %>% 
left_join(my_list_1[[3]] )
```

and so on ... with `map` function.

I tried this:

```
map(as.list(names(my_top)), ~ df  %>% group_by(rank, char_1, points) %>% 
    left_join(my_list_1[[.x]] ))
```

But of course, it is not saving somewhere the joined tibble in order to make a new join with it!

Comment: I'm confused by the `group_by` in your last block of code. You don't need it for joining—are you doing it now in preparation for some other call later?

Comment: True I don't need it for the join, should I remove it?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's just an extra step that isn't needed for the problem at hand, might be needed later. I just wanted to clear up where you were going with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df  %>% 
    group_by(rank, char_1, points) %>% 
    list(.) %>% 
    c(., my_list_1[1:3]) %>% 
    reduce(left_join)
```

Comment: So there is no way to do it with map function?

Comment: @KGeles `map` does things concurrently, but here you wants the output of left_join as input to the next where `reduce` does that i..e suppose you do `map2(my_list_1, df, left_join)` it does the join on each element of list with the df and not the feeding of output from each of the join to the next

Comment: So, in case it was another type of join?

Comment: @KGeles. What you are doing with `reduce` is similar to a `for` loop join `tmp <- df; for(i in seq_along(my_list_1)) tmp <- left_join(tmp, my_list_1[[i]])`

Comment: Arun, I clarified further and posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806913/subsetting-cluster-specific-values-across-a-list-of-data-frame-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer, I'm new here. I had a similar problem recently, join_all was the best solution I found.

```
library(plyr)
#list files that are saved in your computer, for example, in txt format
files <- list.files("path", *.txt)
# open the files and save then as a list
list_of_data_frames <- lapply(files, read_delim, delim = "\t")
# merge files
merged_file <- join_all(list_of_data_frames, by = NULL)
```