# Subsetting cluster-specific values across a list of data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794825/8840683), my goal is to find variables in `m` clusters of data.frames that are specific to only one `m` (e.g., `m[[15]]`) but not other `m`s.

For example, I know variable `genre == 4` is only specific to `m[[15]]` ("Fazio" i.e.,`names(m)[15]`), and `genre == 4` doesn't occur in any other of `m` clusters (confirm by `subset(d, genre == 4)`).

Thus, I expect my output to give me the name `"Fazio"` and `genre == 4` .

I want to repeat this process for all variables shown in `mods` not just `genre`?

**I tried the following with no success:**

```
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/v.csv", h = T) # DATA

mods <- c("genre","cont.type","time","cf.timely","ssci","setting","ed.level",  # mods
          "Age","profic","motivation","Ss.aware","random.grp","equiv.grp",
          "rel.inter","rel.intra","sourced","timed","Location",
          "cf.scope","cf.type","error.key","cf.provider","cf.revision","cf.oral",
          "Length","instruction","graded","acc.measure","cf.training","error.type")

m <- split(d, d$study.name) # `m` clusters of data.frames

# SOLUTION TRIED:

tmp = do.call(rbind, lapply(mods, function(x){
  d = unique(d[c("study.name", x)])
  names(d) = c("study.name", "val")
  transform(d, nm = x)
}))

# this logic may need to change:
tmp = tmp[ave(as.numeric(as.factor(tmp$val)), tmp$val, FUN = length) == 1,] 

lapply(split(tmp, tmp$study.name), function(a){
 setNames(a$val, a$nm)
})                               # doesn't return anything
```

Comment: Do you need to group by `mod` i.e. `tmp[with(tmp, ave(val, val, nm, FUN = length)==1),]`

Comment: the logic is to filter the rows where the length of unique elements in 'val' is 1 based on 'val' and the 'nm' i.e. mods column

Comment: But this just splits up into list, whereas you want something else?  `tmp1 <- tmp[with(tmp, ave(val, val, nm,  FUN = length)==1),]; split(tmp1, tmp1$study.name, drop = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the grouping by adding 'nm' also in `ave`

```
tmp1 <- tmp[with(tmp, ave(val, val, nm, FUN = length)==1),]
```

and now do the `split`

```
tmp2 <- lapply(split(tmp1, tmp1$study.name, drop = TRUE), `row.names<-`, NULL)
rm.df <- data.frame(study.name = c(rep("Bitc_Knch_c", 3),
  rep("Sun", 3)), code = c(88,88,88,7,4,0), 

 mod.name = c("error.type","cf.scope","cf.type","error.type",
     "cf.type","error.key"))
rm.these <- split(rm.df, rm.df$study.name)

tmp2[names(rm.these)] <- Map(function(x, y) {
     subset(x, !(nm %in% y$mod.name & val %in% y$code))}, 
     tmp2[names(rm.these)], rm.these)
Filter(nrow, tmp2)
```

Comment: @Reza 1) Glad to helpo, 2) `drop = TRUE` is to remove the NULL list elements.  If you don't do that, then will get all the combinations (as I am getting it), 3) Yes, just do `lapply(split(tmp1, tmp1$study.name, drop = TRUE), 'row.names<-', NULL)`

Comment: @Reza May be this helps `tmp2 <- lapply(split(tmp1, tmp1$study.name, drop = TRUE), 'row.names<-', NULL);
tmp2[names(rm.these)] <- Map(function(x, y) {y1 <- stack(y); subset(x, !(nm %in% y1$ind & val %in% y1$values))}, tmp2[names(rm.these)], rm.these);
Filter(nrow, tmp2)`

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, that is the part with `subset` where we `stack` the named vector in the `list` of 'rm.these` and remove those specific elements.  Here we are subssetting the 'tmp2 if you check `tmp2[names(rm.these)]`

Comment: Arun, could we possibly remove the following data.frame from `tmp1` in your above answe: `rm.df <- data.frame(study.name = c(rep("Bitc_Knch_c", 3), rep("Sun", 3)), code = c(88,88,88,7,4,0), mod.name = c("error.type","cf.scope","cf.type","error.type","cf.type","error.key"))`?

Comment: @Reza If you check the code, I split the `rm.df` by `study.name` and I am comparing on corresponding 'study.name' elements to remove

Comment: @Reza 'tmp1' is already split up with different 'study.name'.  So, it is more easier to match the same study.name

Comment: @Reza. You meant to get 'tmp1' or 'tmp2'?  I see that you split `tmp1` to create 'tmp2'

Comment: @Reza Did you meant `subset(tmp1, !((study.name %in% rm.df$study.name) & (val %in% rm.df$code) & (nm %in% rm.df$nm)))`